# Using Office.js library in SF Outlook Add-in

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, office-365

I am a .NET dev exploring ways to add features to the default SF Outlook add-in. I inspected the source of the default page of the SF add-in and it uses Office.js, the library used to develop MS Office web add-in (non-VSTO/COM). Ny question is, can I reference and leverage the Office.js library from a custom component I am creating? I would like to extend the add-in to perform some operations on the email body, like adding texts, charts/images, reading the To list, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question. In theory, yes you should be able to use that library assuming that you can download it and upload it as a static resource in Salesforce. The [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-third-party-library.html) doc should help here.